# how incrementing a shared value from several threads affine to one CPU manages to produce correct results with ++ being three instructions?

Tags: c#, multithreading, caching, increment

I thought I know a lot on the subject, but the following puzzles me. I know that on the particular PC I run this on, "_x++" is translated to three assembly instructions (move value to register from memory, increment in register, write back to memory). So why on Earth, when locked to a single CPU the threads incrementing the value manage to not be preempted at the exact time when a value is incremented, but still in a Register and not written back to memory? Does anybody know an answer to this? I'm guessing this works by sheer luck, but I can't exactly prove it.

I was able to make the correct result go away by setting a break point on `inc eax` in the disassembly window in VS, then making a few steps in the debugger, but that's no proof. Not a solid one.

[This code IS NOT THREAD-SAFE on purpose. This is not production code, it serves educational purposes. I'm trying to dig deep into the subject. Of course, with cache lines out of the picture, we get a lot, but still -- three instructions, and not even a single miss, that's weird! This is a 4 core CPU, x64.]

```
{
    private static int NumberOfThreads = 2;
    private const long IncrementIterations = 1000000000;

    private static int _x;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)1;

        Console.WriteLine("Hit Enter");
        Console.ReadLine();

        while (true)
        {
            var barrier = new Barrier(NumberOfThreads);

            _x = 0;

            var threads = new List<Thread>();

            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfThreads; i++)
            {
                var thread = new Thread(
                    delegate()
                    {
                        barrier.SignalAndWait();

                        for (int j = 0; j < IncrementIterations; j++)
                        {
                            _x++;
                        }
                    });

                thread.Start();

                threads.Add(thread);
            }

            BlockUntilAllThreadsQuit(threads);

            Console.WriteLine(_x);

            Console.WriteLine("Actual increments: " + (IncrementIterations * NumberOfThreads));

            if (_x != (IncrementIterations * NumberOfThreads))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Observed: " + _x);
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void BlockUntilAllThreadsQuit(IEnumerable<Thread> threadsToWaitFor)
    {
        foreach (var thread in threadsToWaitFor)
        {
            thread.Join();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you trying to increment `_x` on different threads?

Comment: Matthew, yes. But they are affine to a single CPU core.

Comment: There is no mystery as to why this works with all threads running on single core when x++ is a single assembly instruction, but in that particular case I have x++ as three instructions.

Comment: What is the output you get with the current code and what is the desired output?

Comment: Could you post disassembled instructions around the increment? According to this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) article on MSDN "A thread can be preempted in the middle of the increment or decrement operation — for example, after it has loaded and incremented the count, but before the new value has been stored. While the thread is preempted, the other thread can increment the count, or the finalizer thread can decrement the count.". Also, is this a release or debug build? Can you confirm this happens in both?

Comment: @ananthonline, MSDN is correct, and I know that. This happens in both Debug and Release. The generated instructions around increment are as follows:
`mov         eax,dword ptr [FFEE323Ch];
inc         eax;
mov         dword ptr [FFEE323Ch],eax;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program would be clearer if you used a class with a _x field, rather than using a _x variable that gets hoisted to a closure.  That having been said, the increment would only fail to be atomic if a thread got preempted while it was doing an increment, in particular between the time the load *completes* and the time the store *begins*.  That's a very small window.  It's possible that some arbitrary event could occur and trigger a task switch at that exact moment, but it's not very likely.  Note that it's entirely possible that the amount of time required to run your loop will be such that the ordinary timer-tick events would consistently miss the magic window of opportunity.

If you want to test things a little better, I'd suggest perhaps adding a little code to the loop to randomize the timing a little bit (e.g. using a bona fide auto variable `randThing` initialized to 1, do something like:

```
  if (randthing & 0x20000000)
    randthing ^= 0x20043251); // Number picked out of hat; a primitive polynomial
                              // would be better.
  else
    randthing <<= 1;
```

might cause the loop timing to vary a little from one iteration to the next, in a non-periodic fashion.

Comment: the time window seems to be rather small indeed. It skips a beat only once in 8 hours. I'm guessing that "arbitrary event" kicks in. I will try out that trick. Thanks.

Comment: this works like a charm - hits it every time, inserted the snippet in the loop right before the increment. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mikhail: You mean every time you run the program the increment fails at least once, right?  Not that it fails on every loop iteration?

Comment: yes. Every run the program increment is missed at least once (actually - more than once). Thank you again.